# D3: highlight circle after selecting from dropdown

Tags: d3.js, datalist

I have a datalist dropdown that is populated from a csv. When I select the item from the dropdown I want the relevant circle to highlight.

```
<input type="text" list="initname-datalist" placeholder="Search Project/Initiative.." onChange="initiativeSearch(this.value);">
```

```
function initiativeSearch(initSelection) {
        console.log(initSelection);
            circles.transition()
                .delay(0)
                .duration(500)
                .style("fill", function(d) { 
                    return d.data.initiative_name === initSelection ? "green";})}
```

initiative_name is a column in the csv that populates the dropdown.

console.log(initSelection) is confirming the correct value from initiative_name is being passed but the relevant circle isn't being selected.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. You are using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) but are missing the third operand. It should be something like `return d.data.initiative_name === initSelection ? "green" : "red";`.

Comment: Thanks altocumulus, adding the third operand made the difference. Appears to only work in Chrome though, I also need for IE and Edge and I have similar functions that work in all so I'm a bit miffed why this one won't.

Comment: I changed onChange to onInput and that resolved the issue for IE and Edge

Answer (score -1):

Without a jsfiddle it's difficult not to guess, but I'll venture one anyway:

`circles` actually is an empty selection in the context of `initiativeSearch()`.

Try with

```
function initiativeSearch(initSelection) {
  const circles = d3.selectAll('.circle')
    .transition() // ...and so on
}
```

If your selection is empty, then the check for `d` at the end of the function will never happen.